# Documenting parameters and nodes

Tags: ros, documentation, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any standard way to generate documentation for nodes and parameters in a ros wiki like form?

I tried with rosdoc but I'm getting only the doxygen documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46199/documenting-parameters-and-nodes/) by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) on 2012-10-24**:
Actually a little step has been made with http://ros.org/wiki/rosdoc_lite.. still not enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, there's no automatic way of doing this at the moment.

That being said, it'd be great to have a standard (like XML or YAML-based) way of documenting a node's ROS interface. Then a file like that could be parsed by the wiki.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francesco Sacchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/3259/francesco-sacchi/) on 2012-10-24**:
Probably some documentation should be easy to generate.. the list of nodes can be taken from the CMakeLists.txt file, and for simple nodes also the list of topics can be extracted with some greps... harder if the topic subscription/publication is done not in the main function..